# How do I search a directory of data files and print out how many times a certain word appears in each file?

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep

This is what I currently have, however it prints the total number of times Author appears in all of the files: 128367

```
grep -roh 'Author' $1 | wc -w
```

However how do I print out the word count for each file separately?

Also the argument it's taking is a folder with the files in.

Answer (score 1):

You just could use `grep` to do this. The second `grep` is to filter files with no matches.

```
grep -rc 'Author' ${1} | grep -v ':0$'
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would I make it so it only does this for the .dat files in the directory?

Comment: If there are no subdirectories to search you could use `grep -c 'Author' ${1}/*.dat` where `${1}` is a directory. Otherwise you have to iterate over the files like mentioned by choroba.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the files:

```
for file in "$1"/* ; do
    if [[ -f "$file ]] ; then
        printf %s: "$file"
        grep -o Author "$file" | wc -w
    fi
done
```

You can also use Perl:

```
perl -lne 'BEGIN { $c = 0 }
           $c++ while /Author/g;
           if (eof) { print "$ARGV: $c"; $c=0 }
          ' "$1"/*
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU Parallel:

```
parallel --tag 'grep -oh Author {} | wc -w' ::: *.dat
```

If there are subdirs:

```
find . -name '*.dat' | parallel --tag 'grep -oh Author {} | wc -w'
```